# PHP priority functions declarations

Tags: php, function

I have a question on the way that functions are declared in PHP.

### First test :

File "functions.php" => `functions toto(){ return "1"; }`

Main File

```
    include("functions.php")
    functions toto(){ return "main"; }
    echo toto();
```

### Second test

File "functions.php" => `functions toto(){ return "1"; }`

File "functions2.php" => `functions toto(){ return "2"; }`

Main File

```
    include("functions.php")
    include("functions2.php")
    echo toto();
```

### Results

The first test work and echo "main" 
The second test doesn't work => fatal error "function toto already define"

I make complementary tests :

- in first test : put the functions toto() before include doesn't change the result.
- Create twice functions toto() in the main file create Fatal Error

Someone can explain me how exactly this work ?
Thanks for reading

Comment: Is there `functions toto(){ return "main"; }` typo?

Comment: You define two functions in the global name scope and try to name them the same. That won't work, it results in the error you receive. Either name them different, or put them in different scopes, name spaces or classes. Function names inside some given scope need to be unique.

Comment: You will get errors in both ways. Maybe in first example you load not correct file or error message about misspell in function declaration was hidden

Comment: First test shouldn't work either. The include probably fails silently and that's why it appears to work. Also PHP does hoisting for (non-conditional) function declarations, so all function declarations are pulled up at the top of the file. That's why, in the first scenario, you should have the error triggered in the included file.

Comment: *"**functions** toto()"*? - this is not the real code.

Comment: "functions toto()" this not the real code!
The include work : before create the functions toto() in the main file i user function_exists('toto') and the function returned true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP statements from the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) family do not copy-paste the content of the included file in the context of the includer. The inclusion happens at runtime.

In your first example, the function `toto()` defined in the main file is created during the compilation. Then, on the execution, the `functions.php` file is read and parsed. It generates an error because it attempts to define the function `toto()` that is already defined.

The same happens in the second example during the inclusion of `functions.php`. Also, you get the same error if you declare the function `toto()` two times in the main script.

Either way, the PHP functions and constants cannot be re-declared.
A quick quote from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions.

You can check if a function is already defined (to avoid defining it again) by using the [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) PHP function:

```
function toto() { return 1; }

if (! function_exists('toto')) {
    function toto() { return 2; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Points to the topic

- You can only name one function `toto()` else you get `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare` You can use `if(!function_exists('toto')){ /*declaration*/ }` to prevent that.
- php complies a file complete before including next files, means all functions in a php will be declared, then includes are made. So if the first line includes a file that declares `toto()`, but the next line declares also `toto()`. The declaration in the include throw the `Fatal error`.
- The only way to prevent this is for example wrap in the first file `if(1){ }` around the declaration, so know the `Fatal Error` comes not from the included file.

Test Case:

```
//file1.php
<?php
function toto(){ echo __FILE__; }
//file2.php
<?php
include 'file1.php';
function toto(){ echo __FILE__; }
toto();
```

Call:
**php file2.php**

Result: 
**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare toto() (previously declared in file2.php)**

```
//file1.php
<?php
function toto(){ echo __FILE__; }
//file2.php
<?php
include 'file1.php';
if(1){
    function toto(){ echo __FILE__; }
}
toto();
```

Call:
**php file2.php**

Result: 
**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare toto() (previously declared in file1.php)**

Comment: include 'file1.php';
echo function_exists('toto'); // return true
function toto(){} // not create Fatal error

I am using PHP 5.3.3

Comment: @juliengroud What, can you explain more, dont know what you want to say?

Comment: I create a simple exemple on my server to test and it doesn't work like you told me.
But in my more complexe project : main file => include(file1) => include_once(file 2) => include_once(file 3) => which contains the functions toto(). this doesn't create an fatal error... i don't understand

Comment: @juliengroud It has nothing to do with the PHP Version, if you declare a functionname twice it will throw an fatal error. I gave some tips about the complie process and cases where declaration where handles diff. (if() wrap & function_exists). So you have to check all files (1 2 3) and look how the functions are declared and what other stuff is going on (like in the first line `if(function_exists('toto'))return;`) or whatever. But fact is you can only declare a functionname once (in the same namespace) else an error is thrown. Debug the real code fully.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will watch carefully and try to find the problem.